# SSMS extension is not loading

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, ssms, ssms-addin

I'm trying to create extension for the latest SQL Server Management Studio (17.3, 14.0.17199.0) but it is just not loading. 
I created new VSIX project in Visual Studio, added new item "Custom Tool Window" and then added ssms to install targets in vsixmanifest. After that I just built the project and installed .vsix. Installer correctly found ssms and Visual Studio and installation was "successful" but when I open ssms extension is not loading at all.

Everything is working correctly in visual studio and custom tool window is available in "Other windows" menu. I checked entries in registry and they look fine (they look same as other extension that I have installed and that other extension is working). I checked that dll with my extension is not loaded by ssms.exe process. I tried adding `SkipLoading` key in registry but this also doesn't work.

I am using vs2015 but tried also 2017 with same effect. I checked everything that I could find about this problem but nothing is working.

Comment: Any errors in SSMS ActivityLog.xml?

Comment: No for my extension, http://wklej.org/hash/110643a3daa/

Comment: My extensions are brfs45t5.cnx, pbdtdv00.esk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're using wrong PackageGuid. SSMS loads only authorized packages. If the white list doesn't containt your GUID, SSMS will skip it.

More details: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/6cfe9fb0-53e4-4475-9924-2e2b80035ae3/ssms-2016-extensions?forum=sqltools

ps.: If you change your package guid to an authorized one, it will work.

Comment: Yes, i figured that out by myself but didn't found any reliable source that would confirmed that. But this is just plain stupid. Why there isn't some flag that would allow me to develop my extension? This is not protecting anyone from anything.